# How to convert the parametric solution of $z_x + z z_y = 6x$ to $z = z(x,y)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In the book of PDE by Kumar, at page 22, it is asked that to solve

$$z_x + z z_y = 6x \quad z(0,y) = 3y.$$

I have proceeded as follows:

Let, for example, denote our coordinate as $x = x(s,t)$ s.t $s$ parametrises the initial curve, and $t$ parametrises the characteristic curve. Then
$$dt = \frac{dx}{ 1} = \frac{dy}{ z} = \frac{dz}{6x },$$
with $x(s,0) = 0, \quad y(s,0) = s, \quad z(s,0) = 3s$ (the initial conditions are set by me according the the given initial conditions in the question).

These imply 
$$x(s,t) = C_1(s), \quad \text{for some function $C_1$ of s.}$$
$$z(s,t) = 6 C_1(s) + 3s,$$
$$y(s,t) = 3C_1 t^2 + 3st + s.$$

If I didn't do any algebra mistake, theoretically, I've solved the problem.

However, this is not the "closed form" of the question, i.e I don't know how does $z$ behaves as a function of $x,y$, so I need to solve $t,s$ in terms of $x,y,z$ but as far as I can see, there is no easy way to do that.

**Question:**

First of all, how can we find $z = z(x,y)$ ?

Secondly, is the given answer correct as a parametric form, and how can one check it ?

Thirdly, is there a way to solve the same PDE without appealing to the parametric form of the solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have correctly found the system of ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{ 1} = \frac{dy}{ z} = \frac{dz}{6x }$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{ 1} = \frac{dz}{6x } \quad;\quad dz-6xdx=0$ :
$$z-3x^2=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{ 1} = \frac{dy}{ z}=\frac{dy}{ c_1+3x^2}\quad;\quad (c_1+3x^2)dx-dy=0$

$c_1x+x^3-y=c_2\quad;\quad (z-3x^2)x+x^3-y=c_2$
$$zx-2x^3-y=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE, on the form of implicit equation,  is $c_2=F(c_1)$ :
$$xz-2x^3-y=F(z-3x^2)$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined according to the boundary condition.

Condition :  $z(0,y)=3y$

$0z-2(0^3)-y=F(3y-3(0^2))\quad;\quad -y=F(3y)$

Let $X=3y$ 
$$F(X)=-\frac{X}{3}$$
Now the function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=z-3x^2$ :
$$xz-2x^3-y=-\frac{(z-3x^2)}{3}$$
Solving it for $z$ :
$$z(x,y)=\frac{2x^3+x^2+y}{x+\frac13}$$
If you want to check it, compute $z_x$ and $z_y$. Put them into the PDE and simplify.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You made an error in the first step, $dt=dx$ implies $x=t+C_1$.

Then, $6xdx=dz$ gives $z=3x^2+C_2$ and as third identity one can take $$dy=zdx=d(xz)-xdz=d(xz)-6x^2dx$$ so that $y=xz-2x^3+C_3$.

Now use that there is only one independent parameter $s$ differentiating between the characteristic curves in the solution surface to conclude that $C_2=f(C_3)$ or
$$
z-3x^2=f(y-xz+2x^3).
$$
The function $f$ is fixed by the initial conditions $(x,y,z)=(0,y,3y)$, so that
$$
3y=f(y)\implies z-3x^2=3(y-xz+2x^3)
$$
to get to a formula for the solution.

Comment: I applied the initial conditions that I set, which should not be a problem since $s,t$ are just variables for the parametrisation of curves, and the result should not depend on how I parametrised them

Comment: Thanks for the answer by the way; you are using tricks that I didn't see.

Comment: What about the constant $C_1$, by the way ?

Comment: By the way, do you have any books suggestion on PDEs ?

Comment: As $x=0$ at the initial condition curve, $C_1=0$ everywhere. I do not understand your first comment, the initial conditions are for $t=0$, they do not determine anything but the integration constants for $t\ne 0$.